# jquery autocomplete

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdown list populated with the list of names on my aspx page. I want to use this as a data source for autocomplete in the name textbox.
 Which is the best way to do it in jquery?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery UI now includes an "offical" [autocomplete plugin](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) which is relatively simple to use.  There are numerous 3rd party ones as well many of which work good too.